# NBD client and server on same machine

Tags: deadlock

Is there *any* way to run an NBD (Network Block Device) client and server on the *same* machine without deadlocking the system?

I am very exhausted looking to find an answer for this. I appreciate if anyone can help.

UPDATE:

I'm writing an NBD server that talks to Google Storage system. I want to mount a file system on the NBD and backup my files. I will be hugely disappointed if I have to end up running the server on another machine. Few ideas I already had seem to lead nowhere:

- telling the file system to open the block device using O_DIRECT flag to bypass the linux buffer cache
- using a raw device (unfortunately, raw devices are character devices and FSes refuse to use them as underlying device)

Comment: If you're writing this yourself, this question belong on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a virtual machine (not a container) - you need two kernels, but you don't need two physical machines.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, having the NBD client and server on the same machine has been possible since [2008](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/48cf6061b30205b29b306bf9bc22dd6f0b091461).

Answer (score 0):

Since the [front page](http://nbd.sourceforge.net/) of the Sourceforge project for NBD say that a deadlock will happen "within seconds" in this scenario, I'm guessing the answer is a big "No."

Try to write a more complete question of what actual goal you're trying to accomplish. There's some times that you need to bang away at a little problem, and some times that you need to look at the big picture.